# Responding an Array to another js file how?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js, express

I am trying to respond an Array to another js file and have access to it from there.

I tried to `res.render()` but it throw me an Error that i dont have the module and i dont want to install any Module.

I also tried the `res.json()` but this just showed the array on the browser and i could not do much with it.

Importing and Exporting didnt work.

To fetch the specific url for this array `fetch(/anime)` did not work either, because when i try to start my Server the url("/") it tried to fetch an array which i didnt sent yet. It is because I am sending the html file, which is linked to the other js file.

I hope that i make it clear.

Server.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    app.use(express.static("./animeCatcher"));
    res.sendFile("index.html");
})

app.get("/anime", (req, res) => {
   let animeNames = ["One Piece", "Fairy Tail", "Attack on Titan"];
   res.json(animeNames);
        });
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src= "animeScrape.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

animeScraper.js

```
fetch('/anime')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(animeNames => console.log(animeNames));
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `res.send(animeNames)` or `res.status(200).send(animeNames)`

Also, please remove express.static from route and make it a global middleware:

```
app.use(express.static("./animeCatcher"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
});

app.get('/anime', (req, res) => {
    let animeNames = ["One Piece", "Fairy Tail", "Attack on Titan"];
    res.json(animeNames);
});
```

Your frontend script is right, but can you check in network tab if your API call shows as fetch type:
[image]

Comment: Hey Mihir thanks for your time, but if i `res.send(animeNames)` then it just displayed it on the browser. Do you know how i can use this variable in my other js file??

Comment: Hi @GeorgeHem please check my recent edits to answer